# Multiplying column means for groups by column mean for the entire data

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, statistics, tidyverse

I'm trying to implement the following formula in R for my data below. `nj` is each `group`'s size, `ybarij` is each `group` means on `y1` and `y2` in my data, and `y_doublebar`s are overall `colMeans(dat[-1])` of `y1` and `y2` in my data.

[image]

The hand calculation would be (so the answer should be `24.4`):
[image]

I wonder what I have missed that I can't get to `24.4`?

```
library(tidyverse)

z <- "group    y1    y2
1 1         2     3
2 1         3     4
3 1         5     4
4 1         2     5
5 2         4     8
6 2         5     6
7 2         6     7
8 3         7     6
9 3         8     7
10 3        10     8
11 3         9     5
12 3         7     6"

dat <- read.table(text = z, header = T)

Reduce("+",group_split(dat, group, .keep = FALSE) %>%
              map(~ nrow(.)*(colMeans(.)*colMeans(dat[-1]))))

      y1       y2 
385.3333 396.7500
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two base approaches:

**1) lm**  Define a centered sum of squares function `SS` and apply it to the fitted values of the indicated regression.  The +0 in the regression formula is optional.

```
SS <- function(x, y = x) (NROW(x) - 1) * cov(x, y)

fm <- lm(cbind(y1, y2) ~ factor(group) + 0, dat)
SS(fitted(fm))[1, 2]
## [1] 24.4
```

**2) ave** Replace each element of y1 by the mean over its group, do the same for y2 and apply SS.

```
SS(sapply(dat[-1], ave, dat[1]))[1, 2]
## [1] 24.4
```

**3) collapse** This package has fbetween and fwithin which can be abbreviated as B and W allowing (2) to be written as follows.  This gets rid of the `sapply` in (2) and with W we can similarly write the analogous statement in the Note at the end.

```
library(collapse)
SS(B(dat[-1], dat[[1]]))[1, 2]
## [1] 24.4
```

### Note

Regarding the formula involving Ws in the comments we have the following constructs using fm and SS from above.  The three approaches here are analogous to the three above:

```
SS(resid(fm))
##      y1  y2
## y1 14.8 1.6
## y2  1.6 9.2

SS(dat[-1] - sapply(dat[-1], ave, dat[[1]]))
##      y1  y2
## y1 14.8 1.6
## y2  1.6 9.2

library(collapse)
SS(W(dat[-1], dat[[1]]))
##      W.y1 W.y2
## W.y1 14.8  1.6
## W.y2  1.6  9.2
```

Also we can rewrite the formula in the comments compactly like this:

```
Reduce("+", by(dat[-1], dat[[1]], SS))
##      y1  y2
## y1 14.8 1.6
## y2  1.6 9.2
```

Comment: Can we also obtain the sum of squares (there is 2 of them) bet. the group means by using 'var' instead of 'cov' and then multiply by n-1?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following :

```
library(dplyr)
tmp <- colMeans(dat[-1])

dat %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(result = n() * prod(colMeans(cur_data()) - tmp)) %>%
  summarise(result = sum(result))

#  result
#   <dbl>
#1   24.4
```

Calculate column wise mean of entire data and store it in `tmp` so we don't recalculate it. For each `group` calculate columnwise mean for `y1` and `y2` and subtract it with `tmp`. Multiply the result with each other and number of rows in the group. Finally, we `sum` all the group values together.

Comment: Maybe [of interest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66286649/7223434).