# Adapting a function to tidyverse ecosystem

Tags: r, function, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse

Function `box_m` from `library(rstatix)` currently requires that its first argument NOT include the grouping variable, and its second argument only be the grouping variable. For example: `box_m(d[-1], d$Group)`.

I'm trying to re-write this function such that `box_m2` would work like: `box_m2(d, Group)`.

I have tried the following without success but was wondering if there might be a way to achieve my goal?

```
library(rstatix)
library(tidyverse)

d <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rnorouzian/v/main/memory.csv")[-1]

  box_m(d[-1], d$Group) # How the function currently works

 # box_m2(d, Group) # How I would like the function to work
 
  
# My trial without success to achieve `box_m2`:

  box_m2 <- function(data, group){
    
    dat <- dplyr::select(data, -vars(group))
    box_m(dat, one_of(group))
  }

# New function
  box_m2(d, Group)
```

Comment: May you share some reproducible with expected output so it easier to understand the "problem" you trying to solve. From what you share I can think of several scenarios and way to solve it but I am not sure if my understand match yours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the function with the help of curly-curly (`{{}}`) operator.

```
library(rstatix)
library(dplyr)

box_m2 <- function(data, group){
  dat <- dplyr::select(data, -{{group}})
  box_m(dat, data %>% pull({{group}}))
}

identical(box_m(d[-1], d$Group), box_m2(d, Group))
#[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also convert to symbol with `ensym` and evaluate (`!!`).  In that way, it is flexible to either pass unquoted or quoted arguments

```
library(rstatix)
library(dplyr)
library(rstatix)

box_m2 <- function(data, group){
  group <- ensym(group)
  dat <- dplyr::select(data, -!!group)
  box_m(dat, data %>% 
         pull(!! group))
  }
```

-testing

```
identical(box_m(d[-1], d$Group), box_m2(d, Group))
#[1] TRUE
identical(box_m(d[-1], d$Group), box_m2(d, "Group"))
#[1] TRUE
```